# Grafana: Local snapshot set custom expire time

Tags: grafana

You can see in the following screenshot that I can choose from 4 different expire times. But I want to define my own ones. For example two weeks or one month. Is it possible to add a costum expire time ? If yes how ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible. You should be able to achieve that by forking grafana and then editing this file

`/public/app/features/dashboard/shareSnapshotCtrl.js`

and then building from source.

see this - https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/master/public/app/features/dashboard/shareSnapshotCtrl.js#L19

```
 $scope.expireOptions = [
  {text: '1 Hour', value: 60*60},
  {text: '1 Day',  value: 60*60*24},
  {text: '7 Days', value: 60*60*24*7},
  {text: 'Never',  value: 0},
];
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try. But I have one open question to building from source. I installed grafana with "dpkg -i grafan3.1.1.deb" If i build grafana from source now how can I upgrade/replace my current installation ?

Comment: You should be able to stop your existing compiled grafana using 
   `$ sudo service grafana-server stop`
And then, in your forked directory, you should be able to start your grafana and it should run without issues. This [link](http://docs.grafana.org/project/building_from_source/) should help you.